# SMT-LIB syntax for execution time

Tags: python, smt

I have been working on model generation problem on bit-vectors using SMT-LIB format. I want to know the execution time of my programs. 
I could only found the below statement in the paper 
** "http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.5-r2015-06-28.pdf"**

Some commonly used statistics (e.g., number of restarts of a solver’s propositional reasoning engine) are difficult to define precisely and generally, while the exact semantics of others, such as time and memory
usage, have not being agreed upon yet by the SMT-community.

What is the SMT-syntax for execution time of a program?

Comment: Am I correct, you want to know time estimations for your SMT execution?

Comment: In my opinion, in principle, it should be more fair to time the SMT solver with an independent tool/routine that behaves exactly the same, started and stopped at the same *'time'*, for all of them.